# How can I put a delay before code is execute in Android studio Java

Tags: java, android, delay

I`m creating Simom Says Game, how can I put a delay before code is execute. In picture number 1, I need it to wait 1 sec before it presses automatically on the button.

**Here is the full code:**

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    Button btnGreen, btnRed, btnYellow, btnBlue;
    TextView tvScore;

    MediaPlayer mpSound1, mpSound2, mpSound3, mpSound4;
    Animation animation;

    boolean gameOver = false;
    boolean buttonClicked = false;

    String[] fourColors = {"Green", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow"};
    ArrayList<String> allColors = new ArrayList<>();

    int count = 0;
    int scoreToWin = 8;
    int i = 0;

    public void ClickGreen(){
        btnGreen.startAnimation(animation);
        mpSound1.start();
    }
    public void ClickRed(){
        btnRed.startAnimation(animation);
        mpSound2.start();
    }
    public void ClickBlue(){
        btnBlue.startAnimation(animation);
        mpSound3.start();
    }
    public void ClickYellow(){
        btnYellow.startAnimation(animation);
        mpSound4.start();

    }

    public void game(){
        count = 0;
        i = 0;
        int random;
        random = rand.nextInt(4);
        allColors.add(fourColors[random]);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(i = 0; i < allColors.size(); i++) {
                    switch (allColors.get(i)) {
                        case "Green":
                            ClickGreen();
                            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Green", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case "Red":
                            ClickRed();
                            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Red", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case "Blue":
                            ClickBlue();
                            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Blue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case "Yellow":
                            ClickYellow();
                            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Yellow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.push_down);

        tvScore = findViewById(R.id.tvScore);

        btnGreen = findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);//0
        btnRed = findViewById(R.id.btnRed);//1
        btnBlue = findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);//2
        btnYellow = findViewById(R.id.btnYellow);//3

        btnGreen.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRed.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnBlue.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnYellow.setOnClickListener(this);

        mpSound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
        mpSound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
        mpSound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
        mpSound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound4);

        game();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.equals(btnGreen)) {
            btnGreen.startAnimation(animation);
            mpSound1.start();
            gameOver = !allColors.get(count).equals("Green");
            count++;
            buttonClicked = true;
        }

        else if(v.equals(btnRed)) {
            btnRed.startAnimation(animation);
            mpSound2.start();
            gameOver = !allColors.get(count).equals("Red");
            count++;
            buttonClicked = true;
        }

        else if(v.equals(btnBlue)) {
            btnBlue.startAnimation(animation);
            mpSound3.start();
            gameOver = !allColors.get(count).equals("Blue");
            count++;
            buttonClicked = true;
        }

        else if(v.equals(btnYellow)) {
            btnYellow.startAnimation(animation);
            mpSound4.start();
            gameOver = !allColors.get(count).equals("Yellow");
            count++;
            buttonClicked = true;
        }

        if(buttonClicked){
            if (gameOver) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                if (count >= allColors.size()) {
                    tvScore.setText(String.valueOf(allColors.size()));
                    game();
                    buttonClicked = false;
                    if(allColors.size() == scoreToWin){
                        Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "WON!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/136Mn.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5u2w.png)
[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbyQ7.png)
[Picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ4rG.png)

Comment: You can use `SystemClock.sleep(5000)`

Comment: I used this command and it froze the animations. So it's not good for me.

Comment: I can`t edit the question so I will edit it here.  I`m creating Simon Says Game, how can I put a delay before code is executed without freezing animations. In picture number 1, I need it to wait 1 sec before it presses automatically on the buttons and triggers the animations. I need the animations to be executed in a dealy from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delay like this, to wait 1 second:
`delay(1000)`

Comment: there is no such command "delay(1000);". If you mean the wait() command, it is also not good for me. As I said it freezes the animations.

Comment: Oh yes ? What about : https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html

Comment: Ok but still it freezes the animations

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for adding delay in the android application.

```
import android.os.Handler;

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
        // Add your function here which will be executed after 1 second
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: As you can see in my code, I used this handler code and it still doesn't work for me. It presses the buttons and triggers the animation at the same time.

Comment: Put handler in your onclick event. Instead of putting methods in handler. @amit

Comment: What do you mean? Can you change it and send me the updated code? :) @Rushabh Shah